# Not enough storage error on CGI app under Win64

Tags: delphi, iis, iis-7, cgi

I have a Delphi (hence 32-bit) CGI app running on a Windows 2008 64-bit server that has 24 Gb RAM with IIS7. The web service runs fine for a few days at a time (sometimes a few weeks) and then suddenly starts reporting "Not enough storage available to process this command."

Now I've seen this before in regular Windows apps and it normally means that the machine ran out of memory. In this instance, the server shows that only 10% of physical RAM is in use. On top of that, TaskManager shows only one instance of the CGI executable, with 14Mb allocated. And once it starts it keeps giving the error, regardless of actual server load. No way is this thing *really* running out of memory.

So I figured there is probably some maximum memory setting in IIS7 somewhere, but I couldn't find anything of the sort. Restarting the web server makes the problem go away until next time, but is probably not the best strategy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CGI does not seem to ever unload under IIS7, even though it seems to work under IIS6. This seems to be a problem with the CGI support on IIS7.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an IRPStackSize issue as discussed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177078/en-us).  And the particular cause mentioned in that article is not the only one, apparently.

Comment: Not the case, sadly. We ended up restarting the service over the weekend. Not ideal, but it works.